# The Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: number-theory

Can someone explain how one can go about in finiding certain values of the function?

$\zeta(2)=?$

I have tried using fourier analysis; however it seems overwhelmingly difficult.

Comment: See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_April_23#Pi_and_Even_Zeta_Constants) as well.

Answer (score 0):

$\zeta(s)$ is in generally pretty hard to compute. There is a formula for $\zeta(2n)$, for natural $n$, involving Bernoulli numbers, it is given by:
    $$\zeta(2n) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!} $$

Where $B_k$ is the $k$-th [Bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). There is also a very nice result by Apéry's that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational.

Other than those, closed forms are very elusive for $\zeta(s)$.